# Firestore database read count increases even when data is fetched from cache

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing some data in firestore which my android app loads at startup. I use following method to load this data at application startup.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(ApplicationEx.getUserId()).collection("items").addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {
    if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
        LOGGER.info("items fetched. from cache: " + queryDocumentSnapshots.getMetadata().isFromCache());
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            items.add(queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Item.class));
        }
    }
});
```

When I restart the app, it can be seen that the data is fetched from cache since `queryDocumentSnapshots.getMetadata().isFromCache()` returns true every time. But, when I check the firebase console, I can see that sometimes the document read count increases.

The behavior is not consistent. When I restart the app multiple times in a row, the read count doesn't increase most of the time. But, if I didn't use the app for several minutes and then start the app, the read count increases most of the time.

The stored data doesn't change, so this cannot be due to android synchronizing the changed data.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted firebase support and according to them this is how it works in firestore. Even when items are locally cached, when a listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes, the next fetch reads all documents from server.

I used following mechanism to overcome my issue to some extent.

Write a new firebase cloud function which listens to writes of the collection. It writes the time the collection got updated to realtime database.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.onItemModified = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/items/{itemId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    return admin.database().ref('/users/' + context.params.userId + '/items-updated-at').set(Date.now());
});
```

In android, at app startup, disable network, load items, and enable the network again.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().disableNetwork().addOnCompleteListener(task -> loadItems());

private void loadItems() {
    Utils.getFirestoreCollection(COLLECTION_NAME_ITEMS).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        //Cache loaded items in memory
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().enableNetwork();
    }
}
```

In android, add a listener to the realtime database path where the last item update time is written. When update event is fired, read items again and update memory cache. Store the item updated time in android shared preferences, so when next time update event fires, check whether the updated time of RTDB is higher than the saved time, and read items again only if the RTDB update time is higher than saved time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation on billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing):

> **Minimum charge for queries**
>
> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you
>   perform, even if the query returns no results.

So, your query will incur at least one read, if it hits the server.

Also, in the section headed "Listening to query results":

> If the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example,
>   if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had
>   issued a brand-new query.

This implies that if your listener goes away and comes back more than 30 minutes later (for example, if the app is backgrounded and later foregrounded), then you will be charged for the query again.

If you thing the billing does not add up correctly, and you have a reproducible example that anyone can run, you should [contact Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) with those details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, lets say that a user has already cached all documents in a collection, and keeps the app closed for few hours. When user opens the app, no data is needed to be fetched from server because the local cache is not stale. Even then, is this counted as all documents fetched from the server again?

Comment: As my answer says, quoting the documentation, you will incur at least one read for a query.  The state of the local cache doesn't matter for that one minimum.

Comment: I understand, but my observation is that the read count increases not just by one, but by the total document count in the collection. Is this something expected?

Comment: Without exact reproduction steps, it's not possible to say what's going on in your case.  In general, if you have a problem with billing or the Firebase console, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Yes, you are charged for a read on every document in the query every time the SnapshotListener connects, if it has been disconnected longer that 30 minutes..  So if I have 1000 documents, and the user opens the app 5 times during the day (each more than 30 minutes apart), I will get charged 5000 reads!!  

Not what all the videos lead you to believe..

I have found this (https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) but I can't see how to make this work yet..